# Using [L] flag when redirecting to another host

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

The [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) mention

> You will almost always want to use `[R]` in conjunction with `[L]`
>   (that is, use `[R,L]`) because on its own, the `[R]` flag prepends
>   `http://thishost[:thisport]` to the URI, but then passes this on to
>   the next rule in the ruleset, which can often result in '*Invalid URI
>   in request*' warnings.

Now, let's say I've a rewrite statement as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^pass/?$ https://www.example.com/ [R,NC]
```

Since, here I am redirecting my client to another host/domain, do I really need to pass the `[L]` flag?

Would there be effects if I am also using the `[QSA]` flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question indeed.

In all my testing I couldn't create a scenario where omitting `L` from this rule shows any change in the overall behavior. Only change happens internally as putting `L` flag force `mod_rewrite` to run the `rewrite` loop immediately rather than going till the end of file. So IMO having `L` is better for performance reasons if not for other reasons.

**About `QSA`:** It is absolutely not needed here since `QSA` is needed only when your rule is modifying `QUERY_STRING` which is not the case here.

Comment: I would like to emphasis that omitting `L` flag does make a difference for `internal rewrite` rules.